# Sql script runner

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, scripting

```
Get-ChildItem ".\Stored Procedures\*.sql" | ForEach-Object { sqlcmd -S ServerName -d     DatabaseName -E -i $_.FullName }
```

When I run a batch of scripts from a folder with the above command, if a problem persists in the intermediate script (like create/Alter/DROP DML script in between) then it should stop there only and need to give me an error message.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do a few things:

1. Set ErrorActionPreference to stop
2. Use the -b parameter with sqlcmd.exe utility
3. Capture and log or display output of sqlcmd.exe utility

I [answered a similar a question on another forum](http://powershellcommunity.org/Forums/tabid/54/aft/8882/Default.aspx) and I've re-posted the answer here:

```
echo "select 'Good 1'" > C:\temp\scripts\1.sql
echo "select * from missingTable" > C:\temp\scripts\2.sql
echo "Select 'Good 3'" > C:\temp\scripts\3.sql

$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

ForEach ($S In Gci -Path "C:\Temp\Scripts\" -Filter *.sql | Sort-Object Name) {
    try { 
        $result = SqlCmd -b -S $env:computername\sql1 -i $S.FullName
        $result = $result -join "`n"

        if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) {
            throw "$S.FullName : $lastexitcode : $result"
        }
        else {
            write-output "Success: $($s.fullname) : $result" | Out-File C:\Temp\Scripts\sqllogging.txt -Append
        }
    }
    catch {
        write-output "Failed: $_ " | Out-File C:\Temp\Scripts\sqllogging.txt -Append
        throw
    } 
}
```